# Build set $X$ and on that set such continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Build set $X$ and on that set such continuous function which has values of different signs but at no point it accepts $0$ value. I tried some transformations of $sgnx$ but it didn't help. Can you help?

Comment: $X=\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks $sgnx$ will work for that.